# How can I specify caller identity in cloudformation at runtime?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using cloudformation to deploy a KMS key. Below is the code.

I'd like to specify the current identity on the principal. The identity can be get from `aws sts get-caller-identity`. But I don't know how to get it in cloudformation stack.

```
MyKey:
           Type: AWS::KMS::Key
           Properties:
             Description: "..."
             KeyPolicy:
               Version: "2012-10-17"
               Id: "MyId"
               Statement:
                 -
                   Sid: "Allow administration of the key"
                   Effect: "Allow"
                   Principal:
                     AWS:
                       - # TODO: Get Current User
                       - arn:aws:iam::#{AWS::AccountId}:root
```

If I don't specify the current caller principal, I will get an error:

```
An error occurred: EncryptionKey - Resource handler returned message: "The new key policy will not allow you to update the key policy in the future. (Service: Kms, Status Code: 400, Request ID: d41d4208-65d6-41bc-99d5-4bed07d50d1d)" (RequestToken: a07fd6e1-92f5-b753-fb75-67ab06183881, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest).
```

The current identity arn should be something like:

`"Arn": "arn:aws:sts::ACCOUNTID:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_DevAdministratorAccess_7fa146e5b7abcaa3"`

Comment: You want to get current account id?

Comment: not account id. the current user arn or role arn

Comment: Not possible, without a macro or custom resource.